# El almacenamiento de la configuración de PhpMyAdmin ha sido desactivado

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Acabo de realizar una instalación limpia de una base de datos, y me aparece este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar "Averigüe porque", me envía a una página donde dice que un OK no está llegando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego dice, CREE una base de datos, a lo que sigo las instrucciones -> [imagen](https://i.gyazo.com/1837756ff6faf05647f9eb45714f29a9.png)

Pero luego se crea una tabla de phpmyadmin en donde no se si tengo que configurar algo o no.

Además, por otro lado, aparece este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien conoce estos problemas y sabe que hacer, agradecería una ayuda, dado que no hay mucha info de esto como para explicar correctamente que pasa.

Answer (score 3):

Hola tu problema se resuelve configurando el `phpmyadmin`, para el primer error seguir las instrucciones deben bastar ya que `phpmyadmin` crea automaticamente la base de datos y tablas que necesitas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a error de `blowfish_secret` la forma permanente que sugiero es editar el archivo `config.inc.php` que esta en el directorio de phpmyadmin, en este lugar debe estar la clave que usa `blowfish_secret` de 32 caracteres para el loggin, y los parámetros de acceso para el uso de cookies (Nota: no vi una variación entre versiones) .

Documentacion relacionada: 
[blowfish_secret](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/es/latest/config.html?highlight=blowfish_secret#cfg_blowfish_secret)
[blowfish secret generator](https://phpsolved.com/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator/?g=%5Binsert_php%5Decho%20$code;%5B/insert_php%5D)

```php
<?php

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '###################33333333333##'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH 32 chatracters! */

$i = 0;

$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/*Esto de aquí no lo toques si no es necesario*/
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 36000;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

***Otras recomendaciones:***

Si estas implementando phpmyadmin y tu proyecto usa bases de datos de gran tamaño, o estas en conjunto tienen un gran tamaño (considera como gran tamaño si el archivo de DUMP sobrepasa los 150 mb);  debes considerar que phpmyadmin se ejecuta sobre php y este tendrá un breve pero gran impacto en tu sistema; en este caso te sujeriria utilizar la consola de mysql para exportar e importar tus bases de datos; de lo contrario tendrás que hacer ajustes en tu servidor/configuración: apache, php, mysql un poco mas profundos...

[te dejo este manual (ya debo ir actualizándolo, pero es funcional)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10s_Y4sc_1WSPpm3uDeHv0iBw0XstFLE3/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Ha pasado un año y cuatro meses de este posteo, pero a mi me a pasado el mismo error(el primero). Al encontrarlo, segui todos los pasos y no se me iba el error. Lo solucione agregandole privilegios globales al usuario pma.